# Test Office Add-ins

Tags: excel, office-js, add-in, sideloading, appsource

I have developed an Office add-in for Excel and would now like to test it under production conditions before it is deployed and published in AppSource.
Is there any way to test the add-in under production conditions? The only thing I have found so far is the ability to do this via sideloading (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins#sideload-an-office-add-in-for-testing). But that is not a real test environment for me.  Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sideload is our recommendation to test your add-in before you do public publish.

If you plan to publish your add-in to AppSource and make it available within the Office experience, make sure that you conform to the Commercial marketplace certification policies. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies

After you submit, A validation test will be conducted. 
please pay attention to following areas:

- Add-ins must follow design guidelines without impeding the customer
  experience within the host application.
- Add-ins must be compatible
  with all versions of Internet Explorer 11 and later, and the latest
  versions of Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Apple
  Safari (macOS).
- Add-ins must work in all Office applications
  specified in the Hosts element in the add-in manifest.
- Add-ins must work across all platforms that support methods defined in the Requirements element in the add-in manifest,

For more information about the validation policies, please refers to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#1120-office-add-ins

Comment: That is what I have done so far. But is there no other way to test it? There is no possibility like e.g. an AppSource where you can publish an add-in for test and not have it available for other users? If I understand you right, the ONLY way to test is sideloading the add-in?

Comment: Microsoft totally ignore this issue (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/584). There is currently no proper way of testing and thereby ensure that your product is working. After every deployment to production of our addin I cannot sleep....