# How to test an office excel add-in with other computer

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm newly developing office Add-Ins. I was able to create an Excel add-in using visual studio 2019 with Office / SharePoint development workload (JavaScrip APIs). It was possible to test on my own excel desktop when I press the start button in Visual studio, but I need a test on another computer. I'm planning to publicize this app on AppSource and OfficeStore.

Checking Microsoft's documentation and some other questions here at Stackoverflow I understood that the recommended way to test is: SideLoad.

> [Microsoft's Documentation about testing and debugging office
> add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins)
>
> [Test office Add-ins - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224620/test-office-add-ins)
>
> [Overall Testing Story for Office Add-ins](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/584)

On the other hand, when I started on my desktop the WebApp(task pane) was host in the IIS server as localhost. So, I created a shared folder and put the manifest archive that was available in my machine on the path: Office add-in\ExcelWebAddIn1\bin\Release\OfficeAppManifests. Besides that, accessing another computer I set the trust manually and it works. On the other hand, when I accessed the excel> insert>add-in>myadd-ins> down arrow is not possible to keep going with Microsoft's documentation, and the add-in is not there!

If I try file>options>add-ins is not there too!

> [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing from a network share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)

Is it necessary to host the web app on a real server or Azure before following these steps? or Is it necessary to publish the solution? Besides that how can I include the manifest in excel?

Answer (score 1):

To test an add-in on a machine that is not the machine where the add-in's web app is running, you cannot use "localhost" in the manifest. The manifest must point to the HTTPS URL of the web app.

Comment: Rick, thank you for your reply. Besides that, I would like to know how can I set the manifest in excel because the document's path is different from my excel desktop. I can't find the shared folder for example.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your question.

Comment: In "Sideload Office Add-ins for testing from a network share" (Microsoft's documentation), a section called "Sideload your Add-In" explain some steps to do in excel like "1. Put the manifest XML file of any add-in that you are testing in the shared folder catalog 2. In Excel, Word, or PowerPoint, select My Add-ins on the Insert tab of the ribbon. In Project, select My Add-ins on the Project tab of the ribbon. 3. Choose SHARED FOLDER at the top of the Office Add-ins dialog box." The problem is: I can't find the Shared Folder option on my excel.

Comment: Did you carry out all the steps for sharing a folder and then making it a trusted catalog? If I do this, I see the SHARED FOLDER option.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

- installed and used Node.js
- edited taskpane files etc on node server
- in a browser, visited localhost:3000/taskpane.html and other files, and copied source generated
- on a webserver, placed these generated files, and copied links to these files (only one html and one js needed)
- repalced links in manifest.xml to html file, and in .html file to .js file
- re-upload manifest.xml to reflect changes

It works, with some errors being thrown in the console output.
It does mean that you need to repeat the steps above each time, except for the upload of the manifest.xml.